# Running ansible playbook commands inside docker image using jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, ansible, jenkins

I have a requirement to create docker ansible image and running playbook using jenkins pipeline.

I have created docker image, but I don't understand how docker ansible ssh keys are copied to remote ansible host. Does that setup need to be done in advance?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you are using Jenkins to do this. There is a plugin called "**SSH Agent**" which allows you to run your scripts within SSH private key context even inside a docker container.

First of all, make sure [plugin is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtb7P.png) in Jenkins

Next, register SSH private key in [Jenkins Secrets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGilj.png)

Then you can reuse secret ID in your job like shown in example below:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label "docker"
  }

  environment {
    ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD = credentials('ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD')
  }

  options {
    timeout(time: 60, unit: "MINUTES")
  }

  stages {
    stage('Run Ansible playbook') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'hippolab/ansible'
          args '-u 0:0'
          reuseNode true
        }
      }
      steps {
        sshagent(credentials : ['MY_SSH_KEY_SECRET_ID']) {
          sh '''
            ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
            echo ${ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD} | ansible-playbook \
              --inventory-file hosts \
              --extra-vars ansible_ssh_common_args='"-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=30"' \
              --ask-vault-pass \
              my_playbook.yml
          '''
        }
      }
    }
  }

  post {
    always {
      deleteDir()
    }
  }

}
```

Author experience:

- If **Ansible Vault** is used, the password can be passed to ansible-playbook tool
  using shell pipe
- **StrictHostKeyChecking=no** is crucial unless you set up your slaves statically and has all the nodes keys preaccepted manually
  which is not the case in 99% of occasions
- **ServerAliveInterval=30** can be omitted unless you have strict SSH server on that side which terminates connections due to
  innactivity. Help if some Ansible tasks take long to complete